# An attribute argument must be a constant expression , typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to assign Group name as an attribute for authorize filter.

It will take as below

> ```
> [FilterConfig.AuthorizeAd(Group = "DirectoryName")]
>  public ActionResult GetData()
>   {
>   }
> ```

Insted of hardcoding i tried by adding it as below

> ```
> [FilterConfig.AuthorizeAd(Group = Constants.ActiveDirectoryName)]
> ```
>
> Where Constants is class and created member as below:
>
> ```
> public const  string ActiveDirectoryName = "directoryName";
> ```

Now i want to aceess it from app.config, tried as below

> ```
> [FilterConfig.AuthorizeAd(Group = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Directory_Name"].ToString()
> ```

It is throughing the error msg as "An attribute argument must be a constant expression"

How can i assign the data from config?
Please suggest me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't do that with attributes, they have to be constants as stated in the error message.  If you wanted to get a value from the configuration file, you could do it by passing the key to the attribute, and then in the constructor get the value you want from the configurationmanager

```
    public MyAttribute :Attribute
    {
        private string _config;
        public MyAttribute(string configKey)
        {
            _config = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey];

            ...
        }
    }
```

HTH

Comment: Good answer indeed! Strange it didn't got upvotes. :)