# Making PrincipalPermission role attribute dynamic with the help of web config

Tags: c#, wcf

Let me explain the scenario: when I hardcode the `Domainname\Usergroup`, the permission levels are working perfectly.

But what I want to do is instead of hardcoding the `Domain\Usergroup` in the code, I want to get it from the config file:

```
string xyz = ConfigurationManager.Appsettings["DomainKeyfromConfig"]

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role = @xyz)]
public Response<String> GetString(String request)
{
    // some code
}
```

When I'm trying to do this, I get this error

[image]

Comment: @mac_s please check now , I have added the image

Answer (score 0):

> [CS0182:An attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0182) argument must be a constant expression, typeof
> expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Your screenshot has shown the specific reason for the error.
You can't do that with attributes, they have to be constants as stated in the error message. If you wanted to get a value from the configuration file, you could do it by passing the key to the attribute, and then in the constructor get the value you want from the configurationmanager.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31481820/an-attribute-argument-must-be-a-constant-expression-typeof-expression-or-array

```
 public MyAttribute :Attribute
    {
        private string _config;
        public MyAttribute(string configKey)
        {
            _config = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configKey];

            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for you answer but 
I need to pass the string value in below code/attribute

HERE

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "here I have pass string value")]

Comment: The attribute parameter must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of the attribute parameter type, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).